# mysql query cant order records as needed

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is:

```
+----visits----+
|      id      |
|   client_ip  |
|     date     |
|     type     |
+--------------+
```

It stores all site user visits. Now i need to make a graph by getting data from this table, my query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as hit_counts, date FROM visits GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 25
```

But the idea is that each time i refresh a page on my site, i get a new row inserted in table, and mysql counts 25 records(but i need to limit my query at 25 days(1 day can have 100+ visits), not only 25 records).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, wouldn't adding a where clause that limits your date range do the trick?

Comment: add a `where date > ..` clause and drop the limit

Comment: If you're looking for the most recent dates, you'll need to `ORDER BY date DESC`.

Comment: Wouldn't the number of records equal the number of dates, since you're grouping by `date`?

Comment: I fail to understand what the problem is.  The most recent day will have an increment.  Is that the problem?

Comment: What is the format of your date field in your database. It might be because you are storing the hour as well as the date and therefore, each date is different.

Comment: I think the question needs to be more specific.

Comment: the query you wrote is fine to get the last 25 days records. So what should be the problem? and adding where clause will cause issues as every date may not has
 data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT temp_table.* FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as hit_counts, date
   FROM visits
   GROUP BY date) as temp_table
ORDER BY temp_table.date ASC
LIMIT 25
```

use `DESC` for the last 25 days.

Comment: I think, I misunderstood the question. Removing this. Thanks for pointing me out.